# invoking delegate with generics arguments in c#

Tags: c#, generics, delegates

I have a class:

```
public class MyClass<T>
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

and I want to create a delegate to run on instances of this class, such as:

```
Action<MyClass<object>> myDelegate = myclass => myclass.TestProperty = "hello";
```

However, the above delegate can't be invoked with anything other than a `MyClass<object>`, such as `MyClass<DateTime>` or `MyClass<string>`.

How can I either define the delegate, or modify the delegate so that I can execute the delegate on a `MyClass<T>` where `T` is anything which extends `object`?

**Edit:** This *can* wait until C# 4 if thats when this becomes possible (if so, please still tell me how) although i'd prefer to get on with it now in 3.5

**Edit:** I actually also have a 2nd class:

```
public class MyDerivedClass<T1, T2> : MyClass<T1>
{
    public int OtherProp { get; set; }
}
```

Ideally id like to use the following syntax to define some delegates:

```
CreateDelegate<MyClass<object>>(mc => mc.TestProperty = "hello");
CreateDelegate<MyDerivedClass<object, object>>(mc => mc.OtherProp = 4);
```

Then given an object, id like to see which delegate arguments match, and then run them

Is this possible? What alternatives do I have to create such delegates?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an interface to encapsulate the members of `MyClass<T>` that you need:

```
interface IFoo
{
    String TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Then change your delegate to use that interface:

```
Action<IFoo> myDelegate = myclass => myclass.TestProperty = "hello";
```

**Edit:** And obviously you would need to do this as well:

```
public class MyClass<T> : IFoo
{
    public String TestProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the help, see my comment @Tony and the updated question

Comment: interfaces were the answer, just needed to stop being daft!

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: After thinking about it a bit further, I don't believe C# 4 will actually help you in this case. You'd need the `MyClass` type itself to be variant, but it can't be because it's a class. However...

You could write a generic method to return you a specific action:

```
public Action<MyClass<T>> NewTestPropertyDelegate<T>()
{
    return myclass => myclass.TestProperty = "hello";
}
```

EDIT: I should have mentioned Andrew Hare's suggestion before - but here's another alternative using a base class instead of an interface.

```
public abstract class MyClass
{
    public string TestProperty { get; set; }
}

public class MyClass<T> : MyClass
{
    ...
}
```

Then use `Action<MyClass>`.

Comment: hmm thanks for the info, looks like im going to be out of luck. ive updated the question with a bit more info, think i may have slightly mislead you by oversimplifying the problem :(

Comment: could i not use an Expression<Action<T>> instead, and then modify the expression to the correct T when it comes to apply it?

Comment: @Andrew: Hmm... possibly. Not sure. I'll try to remember to have another look at this later on.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post, but I figured it will help the next person who might want to do this. I tinkered with this idea a bit because I find it to be a very desirable feature. I got delegates that have a generic parameter to work by doing the following:

```
public delegate void AppSettingsHandlerMethodSetKeyValue(string key, T value);

public class AppSettingsHandler
{

    public CacheHandler(AppSettingsHandlerMethodSetKeyValue setAppSettingsVariable)
    {
        SetApplicationSettingsVariable = (AppSettingsHandlerMethodSetKeyValue)setAppSettingsVariable;
    }

    internal AppSettingsHandlerMethodSetKeyValue SetApplicationSettingsVariable { get; set; }

    internal void SetApplicationSetting(string key, T value)
    {
        SetApplicationSettingsVariable(key, value);
    }

}
```

I hope someone finds this helpful. I'm sure someone will have something to say about it, but it works for me.